# Suspend option is not working in elementary OS Loki

Tags: release-loki, suspend

I am having trouble with the suspend option. I have a laptop and I want whenever I close the lid to suspend. I changed it from the Power of the System Settings both for Plugged In and On Battery, but to no avail. I close the lid and it still is on. I tried to suspend it manually from the power button in the top right corner and it shows the same behavior as the Lock option. What can I do? Nothing I found on the web works. It's of importance to me to have the suspend option because of overheating. I should probably say that I am new in the elementary OS. Thank you in advance.

Comment: is `systemctl suspend` working?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you are missing the swap space. Trying adding a swap partition manually. 
You can check if you have a swap space using `free -m` If total swap is 0, you need to allocate some space for swap. Usually taken 1.5x Your RAM size.

Create a 4 Gigabyte or more (according to your RAM size) swap file by typing:

`sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile`

Change permissions for your swap file

`sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`

Now make swap using `sudo mkswap /swapfile` and then **enable the swap** partion by typing

`sudo swapon /swapfile`

Comment: First of, thank you for your time. No, I have swap partition. I have 3GB of RAM and i made 4.1GB swap partition. To be sure, I used the `free -m` command and it shows 3909 total and all of them free right now. But as far as I know, the swap partition is needed for the hibernate option. The suspend option keeps the laptop on, so it keeps everything in the RAM as usual. Maybe it's a bug? Because when I suspend manually from the menu, after 2-3 seconds it locks instead of suspend.

Comment: Try installing pm-utils and then try suspending using `pm-suspend`. See how that works out.

Comment: how do i install it? just with `sudo apt-get install pm-utils`? And what exactly is this? Is there any chance I have this already? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is how you install it. Pm-utils is a collection of shell scripts that wrap the kernel mode suspend/resume with the various hacks. These hacks are needed to work around bugs in drivers and subsystems that are not yet aware of suspend.

Comment: I used the `pm-suspend` and it says "This utility may only be run by the root user." So, I used `sudo pm-suspend`, the screen went black for a couple of seconds and then nothing, it returned to the terminal. Now what should I do?

Comment: Try this as root:
`PM_DEBUG=true pm-suspend`

Then post `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` log file on [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and give the link for me to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56865/discussion-between-shashank-shekhar-and-geo1230).